# three.js Wrong camera position when moving light with TrackballControls

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to move light with my camera.
I wrote:

```
  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, windowWidth / windowHeight, 1, 10000);
  camera.position.z = 50;
  scene.add(camera);


  var dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
  **dirLight.position = camera.position;**
  dirLight.position.normalize();
  scene.add(dirLight);

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setSize(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  i_container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera);

  controls.rotateSpeed = 1.0;
  controls.zoomSpeed = 1.2;
  controls.panSpeed = 0.8;

  controls.noZoom = false;
  controls.noPan = false;

  controls.staticMoving = true;
  controls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.3;

  controls.keys = [65, 83, 68];

  controls.addEventListener('change', render);
```

Everything works: light is moving with camera.
But there is one problem: when scene is initializing camera is inside my object. So I should zoom out to see whole object.

Without this line - "dirLight.position = camera.position;" scene is initializing ok: I see the whole object.

Could you please explain me what is wrong? I do not change position of camera. Why am I inside object?

Thanks,
Zhenya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `TrackballControls`. It is because

```
dirLight.position = camera.position;
dirLight.position.normalize();
```

is normalizing the camera position.

Remove `dirLight.position.normalize()`; it is no longer needed.

In fact, I'd use a pointLight instead, but what you are doing does work under the current version of three.js.

three.js r.58